# Сервер для приложения на TomCat(Java EE)

Tags: java, сервер, java-ee, tomcat, администрирование

Добрый день, уже какое-то время изучаю Java EE и возникла потребность в deploy на удаленный сервер моего приложения. Может кто-нибудь подскажет каких-нибудь хостинг провайдеров именно для этого(желательно бесплатных) или же подходя все удаленные сервера для этого, просто размещения на сервере Java приложения не было, был только опыт с PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам не пользовался, но часто слышал про [хероку](https://www.heroku.com/)

Так же  у них есть [бесплатный тариф](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)